# spring basic authentication plus ip filter

Tags: spring-security

I´m trying to configure a basic authentication plus ip filter, the basic auth, works fine with this configure:

```java
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
        .httpBasic();
}
```

I would like to add ip filter, I´ve read some about `hasIpAddress` but I don´t know how use it.

Comment: I have tried to add: .authorizeRequests()
                              .anyRequest()
                              .fullyAuthenticated()                                                                                              
                              .hasIpAddress("128.0.0.1") but the syntax in wrong

Comment: You should [edit] your comment into your question, because it is important to understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For XML configuraton see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#el-access-web):

> **26.2 Web Security Expressions**
>
> To use expressions to secure individual URLs, you would first need to set the `use-expressions` attribute in the `<http>` element to `true`. Spring Security will then expect the `access` attributes of the `<intercept-url>` elements to contain Spring EL expressions. The expressions should evaluate to a Boolean, defining whether access should be allowed or not. For example:
>
> ```xml
> <http>
>     <intercept-url pattern="/admin*"
>        access="hasRole('admin') and hasIpAddress('192.168.1.0/24')"/>
>     ...
> </http>
> ```
>
> Here we have defined that the "admin" area of an application (defined by the URL pattern) should only be available to users who have the granted authority "admin" and whose IP address matches a local subnet. We’ve already seen the built-in `hasRole` expression in the previous section. The expression `hasIpAddress` is an additional built-in expression which is specific to web security. It is defined by the `WebSecurityExpressionRoot` class, an instance of which is used as the expression root object when evaluation web-access expressions.

For Java configuration see [`ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl#access`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl.html#access-java.lang.String-):

> **Parameters:**
>
> `attribute` - the expression to secure the URLs (i.e. "hasRole('ROLE_USER') and hasRole('ROLE_SUPER')")

Your modified code:

```java
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().access("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasIpAddress('192.168.1.0/24')")
            .and()
        .httpBasic();
}
```